# Is there any way to get original value as 123456789012 for 1.2346E+011 in java?

Tags: java

vendor is making excel and saving as csv file but in one of field the value is coming like 1.2346E+011 but the acutal value is 123456789012 .

Is there any way to get original value  as 123456789012 for 1.2346E+011 in java?

Help is appreciated
Thank You

Comment: how this value is exported into csv?

Comment: Well, if in the CSV it's explicitly written as `1.2346E+011`, you can do nothing, as that means `1.2346 * 10^11`. At best you'll get `123460000000`.

Comment: If information has been lost, you can't recover it. If you have used a format which isn't what you want you can change the format.

Answer (score 5):

`1.2346E+011` is [Scientific Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation). It means:

```
1.2346 * 10^11 = 123,460,000,000
```

So it all depends on what data is saved in the csv file. Go open the csv file with notepad, not Excel, and examine the contents.

If it says `1.2346E+011`, then you can't do anything. The data stored has lost a lot information (7 digits worth!). 123460000000 is a lot different than 123456789012.

If it's a number without an "E" in the middle, then you are fine. Excel might be doing some automatic formatting of your large numbers into scientific notation to keep the data easy to read in small cells.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Apache POI to get the exact value. Please go through POI documentation.

Comment: That's one way to extract the value, but it doesn't do you any good if the format the number is stored in doesn't hold all the information you need.